[Android][ Sending Voice Input to Android TV using Android TV Remote Control v2
I'm currently working on an Android Remote Control application that can connect and control Android TV. I have successfully paired the devices and can now send different keycode commands to control the TV box.
The next feature that I want to implement is about sending voice input to the TV. To open voice input, I can either use KEYCODE_SEARCH(84), manually clicking on Google Assistant, or manually clicking on the Mic icon like in YouTube app.
But what's next?
After a few days researching, there aren't many documents about this and the existing public projects are all using Remote Control V1. As far as I know, I need to do something with RemoteVoicePayload, RemoteVoiceBegin, and RemoteVoiceEnd.
Have you worked on this before? What are the procedures for this? How can I simultaneously speak to the phone and the text get updated on the TV?
Thank you!
(This is my first post on this platform so sorry if I did something not correct)

I.m currently working on it too. As far as I know, after record, you will need to convert file to byteArray, then it will look like (I assume that you have connected TV successful)
fun createVoiceCommandPayload(value: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val remoteMessage: RemoteMessage = RemoteMessage.newBuilder()
            .setVoicePayload(
                ByteString.copyFrom(value)
            ).build()
        return addLengthAndCreate(remoteMessage.toByteArray())
    }

then using outputsteam to write it on, hope it help

Oh I forgot to close this question :). Yes, using ByteString for sending Voice message was the correct approach. Anyway, thank you buddy!

you're welcome, btw, I'm still stuck in when I call remoteVoiceBegin, with VoiceConfig, my socket always close right after that, do you know why, I still cant figure it out. Are there anything else I need to adjust ?

I think you need to do configuration and then send the voice, something like this:
RemoteProto.RemoteMessage.Builder newBuilder = RemoteProto.RemoteMessage.newBuilder();            newBuilder.setVoiceEnd(RemoteProto.VoiceEnd.newBuilder().setSessionId(-1)).build();

Hm, there is no setSessionId method for the builder of RemoteVoiceEnd..

Ok, it turned out that my proto file was missing some field, I was using this the version from this github. I guess I have to add some new fields into this along with the order, something like int32 session_id = 1 for example.

hello, @KoPhaiHoang, did you solve this isse ?
